# Javascript - how to quickly construct a binary representation for an array of distinct positive integers

Tags: javascript, arrays, binary

I am currently working on a Javascript project where I need to quickly generate a unique `group_ID` for a non-empty array of distinct positive integers, such as:

`var a = [1, 2, 5]`

In this case, I would like to identify this array using a binary number: `0b11001` (i.e.,  a binary number says that elements 1, 2 and 5 are in the group and the other elements are absent). Here, the ordering doesn't matter so I would get the same `group_ID === 0b11001` for `[2, 1, 5]` or `[5, 1, 2]`.

I am wondering if there is a quick way to generate this ID using either native JS, or underscore/lodash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to shift 1 to the left by the element to get the corresponding binary number for each element. Then use bitwise "or" to collect them:

```
var groupId = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
   groupId |= 1 << (a[i] - 1);
}
```

Or a bit more "modern" as a one-liner:

```
groupId = a.reduce(function(p, c) {return p | (1 << (c - 1));}, 0);
```

Note that this will only work for numbers up to 32 in JavaScript. For bigger numbers, you'll need to use an array for the group ids (perhaps hidden in a BitSet class)

p.s. For numbers > 32 (and including 0):

```
var groupId = [];
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  var e = a[i];
  groupId[Math.floor(e / 32)] |= 1 << (e % 32);
}
// convert the array to a hex string or similar for simpler handling
```

Comment: even more moderner `a.reduce((p, c) => p | 1 << (c - 1), 0);`

Comment: Thank you! It's unfortunate that there isn't an easy way to make it work for numbers greater than 32. The solution that I came up with is: `groupId = _.reduce(a, function(bin, s){return bin + Math.pow(2,s-1)}, 0).toString(2)` though this outputs a String. Out of curiosity, will JS be faster when working with binary numbers vs Strings?

Comment: Yes binary numbers are faster and your solution needs a check for duplicates (if they may occur) and it's still limited to 53